# Phalcon, как правильно разобрать URL?

Tags: php, url, чпу, phalcon

Есть URL: http://localhost/**page/example/edit/123**
собственно, как правильно получить значения строк: **page/example/edit/123**
Первое, что приходит на ум: 
`$variables = explode('/', $this->request->get('_url'));`
но по моему обращаться через ключи не особо удобно...

Пробовал через роутинг, но переменные, которые я там указываю не могу получить.
Пример:
index.php:

```
$router->add("/([a-z])/([a-z])/([a-z])/([0-9])",
array(
"controller" => "myController",
"action" => "my",
"var1" => 3,
"var2" => 4,
)
);

$router->handle();
```

Ну и код контроллера:
myController.php:

```
public function myAction()
{
echo 'Зачение: '.$this->dispatcher->getParam("var1");
$this->view->disable();

}
```

В итоге выводит:

> Зачение:

хотя мне нужно чтобы вывело: Значение: edit
Собственно, как быть? как проще разобрать URL?

Comment: Может следует заменить регулярку "/([a-z])/([a-z])/([a-z])/([0-9])" на правильную "/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых в [Phalcon, как правильно разобрать URL?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/438090/phalcon-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-url#comment458317_438090) правильно указано - регулярку надо поменять.

Во-вторых, советую испоьзовать именованные параметры:

```
$router->add("/[a-z]+/[a-z]+/{var1:[a-z]+}/{var2:[0-9]+}",
    array(
        "controller" => "myController",
        "action" => "my",
    )
```

);